# Why I obtain this error message when I try to create a new Laravel projct using Composer?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I am absolutly new in **Composer** and in **Laravel** framework.

I am trying to create a new Laravel 5.2 project using Composer to download it performing this statment in the GIT Bash shell:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel cms 5.2
```

But I am obtaining the following error message:

```
$ composer create-project laravel/laravel cms 5.2
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.2.0)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.2.0) Downloading: 100%
Created project in cms
> php -r "copy('.env.example', '.env');"
> php artisan clear-compiled

Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed t
o open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\bootstrap\autolo
ad.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\bootstrap/.
./vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms
\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
PHP Warning:  require(C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): fai
led to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\bootstrap\a
utoload.php on line 17
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\bootst
rap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdoc
s\cms\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned wit
h error code 255
```

Why? What could be the problem? Something related Windows folder permission or what?

How can I try to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you typed that `php -r (...)` and `php artisan clear-compiled` yourself? Cause it appears to me that composer hasn't even created a compiled class yet, so it's no wonder it can't find them.

Comment: Your project seems to be already created: `Created project in cms`. You got this error in `php artisan clear-compiled`. Not sure why, but you should already have all the required files. You can try to create a project [Via Laravel Installer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/installation#installing-laravel) instead of **Via Composer Create-Project**.

Comment: Did you tried passing --no-scripts argument.

Comment: @Loek no I have only performed the composer statment

Comment: confirm the minimum server requirements for installing laravel

Answer (score 1):

It appears composer is trying to flush the compiled files which aren't created yet.

Step 1) Install Laravel without scripts

```
composer create-project --no-scripts laravel/laravel cms 5.2
```

Step 2) Run post install scripts manually.

```
cd cms    
composer run-script post-install-cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

you are having problem because your version value is not complete. you also have to put subversion or asteric(*) symbol

you have to use following command for achieve what you want

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel cms 5.2.*
```